# If $X$ is a cone, show that $I(X)$ is homogeneous.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

<sub>The exercise is 1.3(3) from HP Kraft, "Appendix A: Basics from Algebraic Geometry."</sub>

**If a closed subset $X\subseteq \mathbb C^n$ is a cone, show that $I(X)$ is generated by homogeneous functions.**

<sub>Closed means $X=\cap g_i^{-1}(0)$ the zero set for some $g_i\in\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$; cone means $tv\in X$ for all $v\in X,t\in \mathbb C$; the ideal $I(X)$ means polynomials that vanish on $X$; the exercise defines homogeneous to mean $f(tv)=t^df(v)$ for all $v\in \mathbb C^n, t\in \mathbb C$ for some $d\in\mathbb N.$</sub>

The exercise appears before Nullstellensatz and affine variety are introduced, but I can't find an elementary proof anywhere. [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousIdeal.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_variety) (citing "Chow's theorem") give the statement without proof. The converse is trivial of course.

---

**Solution** (paraphrasing Georges [below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/568551/109082)). Every polynomial can be written as the sum of homogeneous polynomials $p(x) = p_0 (x)+\dots +p_d(x).$
These homogeneous components generate "at least" as much,
$$\sum_{p\in I(X)} (p_1)+\dots+(p_d) \supset I(X).$$

To show the reverse inclusion, we fix $p\in I(X)$ and show that each component $p_i\in I(X).$
Let $v\in X$ be given. Since $X$ is a cone, $p$ vanishes on the line $\mathbb C v,$ and $$p(tv) = \sum p_i(tv) = \sum p_i(v) \, t^i=0$$ for all $t\in \mathbb C.$ Thus $p(tv)\in \mathbb C[t]$ must be the zero polynomial with every "coefficient" $p_i(v)=0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to show that if a polynomial $p(T_1,...   ,T_n)=\sum p_d(T_1,...   ,T_n)$ vanishes on the line $l=\mathbb C\cdot a $ where $a=(a_1,...,a_n)\neq 0\in X\subset \mathbb C^n$, each of the  homogeneous components $p_d(T_1,...   ,T_n)$  of degree $d$ of the polynomial $p(T_1,...   ,T_n)$ vanishes on $l$.

But since $p(z\cdot a)=\sum p_d(z\cdot a_1,...   ,z\cdot a_n)=\sum z^d\cdot p_d( a_1,...   , a_n)=0$ is a polynomial in $z$  vanishing for all $z\in \mathbb C$, that polynomial is zero and  we necessarily must have $p_d( a_1,...   , a_n)=0$ for all $d $, i.e. all homogeneous components $p_d$ of $p$ vanish on $l$.

We have thus proved that $I(X)$ is indeed a homogeneous ideal.